# How to keep a text object a" when it contains a breakline?

Tags: cursor-motions

I noticed that if I have a quoted string which contains one new line character I can't use the text objects `i"` and `a"` anymore. For example if I have:

```
This is some text which is less than 80 character and "this is a quoted string
which contains a line break"
```

When my cursor is on the word `string` using `va"` will not work.

This behavior is consistent with what [`:h aquote`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#aquote) says:

> Only works within one line.

**My questions are:**

- Is there a built-in text object which would have the same behavior as `a"` but accepting breakline?
- If not is there a plugin which implement it? (I didn't find a relevant one)
- If not is there a good reason which makes that is hasn't been implemented?

Comment: https://github.com/beloglazov/vim-textobj-quotes says it supports multiple lines. (Requires https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking of a reason why Vim doesn't have this by default ...

At least in VimL and C/C++, to have a string span multiple lines, you can't really have an opening delimiter on a line, and just the ending one on another. `"this is a quoted string` is an end-of-line comment in vimscript, not an unfinished string. For example, with C, you have to use something like:

```
printf("first very long line "
       "second line, in code ");
```

So, briefly put, a multiline string (quote, text lines, quote) is not necessarily a *valid* multiline string.

I agree it can be useful for other filetypes (text, markdown). Even though, for *text*, perhaps you'd want to use a [typographic quotes](https://github.com/reedes/vim-textobj-quote) solution?

To complement [FDinoff's comment/solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5000/how-to-keep-a-text-object-a-when-it-contains-a-breakline#comment7627_5000) of using [vim-textobj-quotes](https://github.com/beloglazov/vim-textobj-quotes): if your filetype has syntax support, and the multiline quoted string appears as a separate syntax item, you  can select the whole block using [Kana's syntax](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-syntax) text object. In the above example, both strings will be selected at once, when using something like `viy` or `vay` with cursor inside any of them.

I like the syntax-based approach because it's not limited to multiline *strings*: I can very well select an entire multiline comment in exactly the same way. And I'm also pretty sure the selection is a valid one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The justification of the end of line comment is exactly what I was looking for. I'll test the syntax-based approach first because I think it is pretty smart and if I'm not satisfied I'll see how to use FDinoff plugin.

Comment: You're welcome; my gain is that it made me give a better look to the typographic quotes plugin (by `reedes`).